# undefined method activity feed and acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this set up in my **ActivitiesController:**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    following_ids = current_member.following_members.map(&:id)
    @activities = Activity.where("member_id in (?)", following_ids.push(current_member.id)).order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

This set up in my **FollowsController:**

```
def create
    @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:member_id])
    @follow_member = current_member.follow(@member)
    if @follow_member
        current_member.create_activity(@follow_member, 'followed')
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @member }
          format.js 
        end
    end 
end
```

And this set up to display the activity of following another member:

```
<div>
    <span class="status_name">
        <%= link_to activity.member.user_name, profile_path(activity.member) %>
    </span> 
    <span>
        is now following <%= link_to activity.targetable.following_member.user_name, "#" %>
    </span> 
    <span class="meta">
        <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.targetable.created_at) %> 
    </span>
</div>

<div class="act_content">
    <%= follow_profile_link activity.targetable.following_member %>
</div>
```

I was able to get the following action to create a new activity item in the feed just fine but I can't figure out how to call to the member who's being followed. I get this error:

```
undefined method `following_member' for #<Follow:0x835b150>

app/views/activities/follow/_followed.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_activities_follow__followed_html_erb__269116874_68857716'
app/views/activities/index.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_activities_index_html_erb___16061925_44845644'
app/views/activities/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_activities_index_html_erb___16061925_44845644'
```

I can't figure out what I need to do or what specifically to call to make this work. Any ideas?

**EDIT - Models**

**Activity Model**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :targetable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Follow Model**

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  # NOTE: Follows belong to the "followable" interface, and also to followers
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :follower,   :polymorphic => true

  def block!
    self.update_attribute(:blocked, true)
  end

end
```

**Member Model**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                :first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :pursuits, :avatar, :bio, :city, :state, :country, :pursuit_list

 has_many :medium
 has_many :statuses
 has_many :activities
 acts_as_follower
 acts_as_followable
 acts_as_ordered_taggable
 acts_as_ordered_taggable_on :pursuits

 def create_activity(item, action)
    activity = activities.new
    activity.targetable = item
    activity.action = action 
    activity.save 
    activity
 end
```

**Edit - Activities Migration**

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|
        t.integer :member_id
        t.string :action

        t.integer :targetable_id
        t.string :targetable_type

        t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :activities, :member_id
    add_index :activities, [:targetable_id, :targetable_type]

  end
end
```

**Activity Index**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <div class="status">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1 stream_av">
                    <%= avatar_profile_link activity.member %>
                </div> 
                <div class="span7">

                    <%= render partial: "activities/#{activity.targetable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}",
                        locals: { activity: activity } %>

                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
<% end %>
```

**New activity for uploading media**

```
<div>
    <span class="status_name">
        <%= link_to activity.member.user_name, profile_path(activity.member) %></span>     <span>uploaded new <%= link_to "Media", profile_media_path(activity.member) %></span>     <span class="meta"> <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.targetable.created_at) %>
</span>
</div>

<div class="act_content">
    <%= link_to image_tag(activity.targetable.asset.url(:medium), class: ''), medium_path(activity.targetable_id) %>
</div>
```

**New activity for writing a status**

```
<div>
    <span class="status_name">
        <%= link_to activity.member.user_name, profile_path(activity.member) %></span>     <span>wrote a <%= link_to "Post", profile_stream_path(activity.member) %></span>     <span class="meta"> <%= time_ago_in_words(activity.targetable.created_at) %>
</span>
</div>

<div class="act_content">
    <%= activity.targetable.content %>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the rest of the error?

Comment: can you show your models?

Comment: @sevenseacat I just edited the message but that was about all there was to it.

Comment: @rb512 I just posted my models as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**following_member** returns an ActiveRecord object. So, you gotta do something like:

```
activity.targetable.following_member.first.user_name
```

instead of

```
activity.targetable.following_member.user_name
```

If you want to retrieve all the following members, you'll have to iterate through it.

```
<%activity.targetable.following_member.each do |member| %>
  <%=member.user_name%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Well each activity(i.e. writing a status, uploading a picture, etc.) has a targetable_type & targetable_id. But I changed the code to member instead of targetable and I think that's closer but now I'm getting `undefined method 'user_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x554c7c0>` When I use first it gets the first member I've ever followed not the specific member I just did.

Comment: But I think I'd need to use targetable because I'm trying to call the member I followed from that specific action.

Comment: I'm not following you.  What is targetable and how is it related to your member model?

Comment: I already had models for creating statuses, uploading media, and following members. Then I created an activity model to create a feed that displays all these actions. Targetable is just the status, media, or follow categorized by targetable_type and targetable_id, so only the activity, which is what gets posted to the new feed, belongs to targetable, in other words belongs to status, or media, or follow. I posted the migration, the index, and the partials showing how I display new activities for status and media. These work just fine with targetable. I hope that's more clear.

Comment: alright, so if i got it right, targetable can be any of the following types? : Activity, Member, Status, etc?

Comment: Yes correct it's just referring to those models that will create activity items

Comment: in that case, you should check the records for the activity object in question (by calling the all_following method on your activity object).  This will help figure out if you really have the object you're trying to access.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I have the correct object though because when I actually follow a member it does the correct action and creates the activity item. It's just when I try to call that member I followed (i.e. user_name, avatar) I get the undefined method. But if I say `.first` or `.last` or something there's no undefined method but not the right member. I can't figure out the problem since everything works as expected with statuses and media. I may have to put this on hold and come back to it.

Comment: well, i brought that up already and it's in my answer as well!  if you try to retrieve user_name from a collection of Member objects, of course you're gonna get an error.  You need to figure out what object you want to show and retrieve that object from the collection returned.  Makes sense?

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense now